# What is the best practice for supporting different versions of ODP.NET (Oracle.DataAccess.dll) in an off-the-shelf product?

Tags: .net, oracle, configuration

**Problem**

I work on a .NET COTS product that supports Oracle DBMS. My users may have Oracle client (and corresponding ODP.NET) with version 9i, 10g, 11g, or 12c installed. I build against a specific version of ODP.NET (2.102.2.20), and if the user has installed a different version, they get "Oracle.DataAccess not found" error.

**Things I've tried**

1. *WORKED:* Users manually add/edit a `dependentAssembly` section in the `.exe.config` files:

`<dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="Neutral" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.102.2.20" newVersion="4.121.1.0" /><publisherPolicy apply="no"/></dependentAssembly>`

2. *DID NOT WORK:* Use range for `newVersion` (yeah, [MSDN doesn't say you can do this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx), but I tried; note that using range for `oldVersion` *is* supported but does not help me).
3. *DID NOT WORK*: Telling users they must install one specific version of Oracle client. (Technically it does work, but IT depts and managers hate this idea.)
4. *WORKED:* Created an external configuration tool to search the app domain for the `Oracle.DataAccess` assembly (using `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`), filtering by architecture (32-bit or 64-bit), sorting by version, grabbing highest supported version, and manually writing the `.exe.config` files using the highest detected version, but this is a bit clunky and possibly error prone and may be problematic for upgrades.

**Question**

Is there a better way to do this? Like an *automatic* way that I don't have to code myself?

Solutions 1 and 4 worked, but 1 is an annoying thing to have users do, and 4 just seems..weird (tho this is what I am currently shipping).

It seems like it would be nice if there was a way to state that this assembly (ODP.NET) works fine with any range of versions, but I don't see a way to specify an acceptable range for `newVersion` (you can add multiple `dependentAssembly` nodes, but this crapped out at runtime when I tried adding entries for versions I didn't have installed.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is probably to use the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html) and install whatever version of the client you want as part of your application's installation.  That way, you can ship whatever version of ODP.Net you compiled against along with your application regardless of what other Oracle software happens to be installed.

Comment: In general I have **very** bad experience when you install more then one Oracle Client on one machine, I really do not recommend this. Only exception is to install both 32 bit and 64 bit Oracle client on one machine, however this procedure requires some manual changes on the PC.

Comment: @Wernfried - Are you talking about installing more than one version of the full Oracle client?  Or having multiple applications using their own versions of the instant client?  The whole point of the Instant Client is to allow applications to install whatever supporting libraries they need at install time so I'm not sure what problems you're having.  Multiple versions of the full client can, indeed, be problematic if you're relying on some component that is not multi-home compatible.

Comment: I never installed only the Instant Client by myself. I think you always have to "play" with your `PATH` variable in order to make it working - unless you install all Oracle files into your application directory.

Comment: I have multiple versions and architectures of Oracle client installed just fine, but yeah you need to manage the path to Oracle home in this case. Thanks for suggestions I will try these when I get back in the office next week!

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to use the **ODP.NET Managed Driver**. You can download it from here: [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

Then you have to provide only a single dll `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` with your application and you are not dependent on any Oracle Client installation.

Another solution is to set your `.exe.config` something like this:

```
<dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" /></dependentAssembly>
```

i.e. without any Version, processorArchitecture or publicKeyToken information. 
The application will load the correct `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` depending on selected architecture and target .NET framework. However, it solves only the "32 bit vs. 64 bit" issue and the release of Oracle Client (9i, 10g, 11g, 12c). Selected target .NET framework still has to match the version of ODP.NET (1.x, 2.x, 4.x)